# How would I go about autosizing columns in an Excel sheet only up to a certain row in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and have an Excel worksheet that includes a data table, in addition to some notes at the bottom. I only want to autosize the columns of the data table, but not the notes. Is there a way to autosize columns, but only up to a specified row?

Comment: You can use the macro recorder to give you code to start with.

Comment: First try doing something by hand only then try in VBA. The reason is what you are trying to achieve is not straight forward.

Comment: can you post a picture of how you want the column widths to be?

Answer (score 2):

What might be easier and faster is to determine you range without the notes and autofit the column width

```
Range("A1:A3").Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: nice. I didn't even think to try this. I thought it wouldn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way around it through VBA. Mine is a simplistic example that deletes the note cells from the sheet, AutoFits the columns, then puts notes back in place.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoSizeExclNotes()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1

        Dim sNotes As String
        sNotes = .Range("B6").Value2

        With .Range("B6")
            .ClearContents
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Value = sNotes
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Comment: Nice! I was thinking too, if you didn't know `B6` was the notes, we can assume the notes are the cell with the most characters, so you could loop through a range, and whichever cell's `LEN()` is longest, that's the note.

Answer (score -1):

When you can perform what you want manually, you may simply record a macro and check the code Excel has generated. It helped me out many times.

In your case, supposing you want to autosize cells A1 to A3 only, start the macro recording, select cells A1:A3 and select menu Home > Format > AutoFit Column Width... You then obtain the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

It is certainly not perfect, but it is a good start to learn. Excel is sometimes exhaustive (especially with the SaveAs feature), but you can then use the help to understand the options and rule out the ones you don't need.

Comment: DV for lack of ingenuity and "you can't" in an answer without much real research or reason.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I can only thank you for the DV, it was only deserved. My initial answer was so badly written...

Comment: I really don't mean to keep picking on you, but your updated answer is essentially the same as provided by mooseman below (1 hour before you updated). I would take the DV away since you did provide a little more tip about recording macro and such, but the answer is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: That's right. The only addition is how to obtain it in a general manner (by recording a macro). The outcome is eventually the same.